# Linux Mint: Overwrite existing keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

When I press `Super + Shift + S` the Sound Settings icon popups by default as shown in the following image

[image]

I want to overwrite this shortcut to grab a screenshot area as follows

[image]

How can I do this? I am unable to overwrite the shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the *Sound settings* you described, then

- *Configure* → *Show Menu*, then
- click on the shortcut `Shift + Super + S`, then
- press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

You also have, if I remember correctly, to remove it in the *Keyboard* menu (your second picture):

- *Universal Access* → *Turn screen reader on or off*.

Then it should work!

Comment: How do you do this on Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria?